# How to test same time submissions of form from different location

Tags: javascript, php, testing

I have a exam form that is filled by students and send to the server. The answers are recorded to the database. At some point it turned out that there are to may exam takings and sometimes students answers are not recorded as the database was busy at this time with recording someone else results. I can fix this with using transactions or just check the result of the SQL query and if has failed I can try again but I also would like to do automated test on this issue to make sure that all works fine.
Basically the test should submit the exam multiple times from different browsers / locations so I can simulate a lot of students takings of the exam in the same time.

I'm not sure what tool I should use for this kind of test. I have read a little of PhantomJS and headless browsers but I coudn't find if they can allow tests from different "browsers". Also any ideas on how such tests are performed are more then welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: why shouldn't it work? if everything is made properly it will work.

Comment: Some individual instances of PhantomJS should help you solve this.